# Bash: Read in file, edit line, output to new file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, rhel

I am new to linux and new to scripting. I am working in a linux environment using bash. I need to do the following things:
1. read a txt file line by line
2. delete the first line
3. remove the middle part of each line after the first
4. copy the changes to a new txt file

Each line after the first has three sections, the first always ends in .pdf and the third always begins with R0 but the middle section has no consistency.

Example of 2 lines in the file:

```
R01234567_High Transcript_01234567.pdf  High School Transcript  R01234567
R01891023_Application_01891023127.pdf   Application R01891023
```

Here is what I have so far. I'm just reading the file, printing it to screen and copying it to another file.

```
#! /bin/bash
cd /usr/local/bin;
#echo "list of files:";
#ls;
for index in *.txt;
do echo "file: ${index}";
echo "reading..."
exec<${index}
value=0
while read line
do
   #value='expr ${value} +1';
   echo ${line};
done
echo "read done for ${index}";
cp ${index} /usr/local/bin/test2;
echo "file ${index} moved to test2"; 
done
```

So my question is, how can I delete the middle bit of each line, after .pdf but before the R0...?

Comment: What's your question? There's a lot about this code that can/should be improved, but suggesting random improvements isn't what StackOverflow is for; we're a Q&A community -- we want concrete, focused questions (and give them concrete, focused answers).

Comment: Read about [`sed`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sed.1.html), especially the `s` command. Or read [about AWK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK).

Comment: Sorry, added my question to the end. Got lost in trying to give a detailed description.

Comment: Are the fields in your file actually separated by spaces, or is it literal tab characters between them?

Comment: If it's literal tabs, that allows for a much more reliable solution (one that doesn't have to assume `.pdf` extension or `R0` prefixes).

Comment: The fields sometimes have spaces within them. For instance on example line 1

'R01234567_High Transcript_01234567.pdf'

this one piece of data has a space in the middle and 

'  High School Transcript ' 

this 2nd section has a space in the middle

Comment: Yes, I know they can have spaces inside them; my question is whether they're separated by literal tab characters (`\t`, aka `^I`, aka ASCII character 9).

Comment: If you're on a GNU system, try using `cat -A yourfile` and see if the spaces between the fields (not the ones inside the fields) change into `^I` sequences.

Comment: ...if you're on MacOS, the equivalent would be `cat -t`.

Comment: They do change into ^I between the sections

Comment: Then you have a robust, reliable and easy solution -- see the end of my answer.

Comment: ...or JNevill's awk-based amendment (at the top of their answer presently), which should work just as well.

Comment: Thanks for your time and help I was able to get it working with the awk solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Updated answer assuming tab delim

Since there is a tab delimiter, then this is a cinch for awk. Borrowing from my originally deleted answer and @geek1011 deleted answer:

```
awk -F"\t" '{print $1, $NF}' infile.txt
```

Here `awk` splits each record in your file by tab, then prints the first field `$1` and the last field `$NF` where `NF` is the built in `awk` variable for the record's Number of Fields; by prepending a dollar sign, it says "The value of the last field in the record".

### Original answer assuming space delimiter

Leaving this here in case someone has space delimited nonsense like I originally assumed.

You can use `awk` instead of using bash to read through the file:

```
awk 'NR>1{for(i=1; $i!~/pdf/; ++i) firstRec=firstRec" "$i} NR>1{print firstRec,$i,$NF}' yourfile.txt
```

`awk` reads files line by line and processes each record it comes across. Fields are delimited automatically by white space. The first field is `$1`, the second is `$2` and so on. `awk` has built in variables; here we use `NF` which is the Number of Fields contained in the record, and `NR` which is the record number currently being processed.

This script does the following:

1. If the record number is greater than 1 (not the header) then
2. Loop through each field (separated by white space here) until we find a field that has "pdf" in it (`$i!~/pdf/`). Store everything we find up until that field in a variable called `firstRec` separated by a space (`firstRec=firstRec" "$i`).
3. print out the `firstRec`, then print out whatever field we stopped iterating on (the one that contains "pdf") which is `$i`, and finally print out the last field in the record, which is `$NF` (`print firstRec,$i,$NF`)

You can direct this to another file:

```
awk 'NR>1{for(i=1; $i!~/pdf/; ++i) firstRec=firstRec" "$i} NR>1{print firstRec,$i,$NF}' yourfile.txt > outfile.txt
```

`sed` may be a cleaner way of going here since, if your `pdf` file has more than one space separating characters, then you will lose the multiple spaces.

Comment: BTW, it turns out the OP's file is actually tab-separated, so all this string-matching is utterly unnecessary.

Comment: Doh! I stuck an updated version to the top of the answer that doesn't go through the iterating and stitching of strings to make awk battle a space delimited file with spaces in the data. It was good for practice though! Right? Right?

Comment: Your updated answer worked like a charm! I am going to start reading more about awk so I can continue to add functionality to this script.

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed`:

```
sed 's/^\(.*\.pdf\).*\(R0.*\)$/\1 \2/g' file.txt
```

This will remove everything between `.pdf` and `R0` and replace it with single space.

Result for your example:

```
R01234567_High Transcript_01234567.pdf R01234567
R01891023_Application_01891023127.pdf R01891023
```

Answer (score 2):

#### The Hard, Unreliable Way

It's a bit verbose, and *much* less terse and efficient than what would make sense if we knew that the fields were separated by tab literals, but the following loop does this processing in pure native bash with no external tools:

```
shopt -s extglob
while IFS= read -r line; do
  [[ $line = *".pdf"*R0* ]] || continue # ignore lines that don't fit our format

  filename=${line%%.pdf*}.pdf
  id=R0${line##*R0}
  printf '%s\t%s\n' "$filename" "$id"
done
```

`${line%%.pdf*}` returns everything before the first `.pdf` in the line; `${line%%.pdf*}.pdf` then appends `.pdf` to that content.

Similarly, `${line##*R0}` expands to everything after the last `R0`; `R0${line##*R0}` thus expands to the final field starting with `R0` (presuming that that's the only instance of that string in the file).

---

#### The Easy Way (Using Tab Delimiters)

If `cat -t file` (on MacOS) or `cat -A file` (on Linux) shows `^I` sequences between the fields (but not within the fields), use the following instead:

```
while IFS=$'\t' read -r filename title id; do
  printf '%s\t%s\n' "$filename" "$id"
done
```

This reads the three tab separated fields into variables named `filename`, `title` and `id`, and emits the `filename` and `id` fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed` on each `line` like that:

```
line="R01234567_High Transcript_01234567.pdf  High School Transcript  R01234567"
echo "$line" | sed 's/\.pdf.*R0/\.pdf R0/'
# output 
R01234567_High Transcript_01234567.pdf R01234567
```

This replace anything between `.pdf` and `R0` with a spacebar.
It doesn't deal with some edge cases but it simple and clear

Comment: Running one `sed` invocation per line is paying quite a large performance penalty; if this file had hundreds or thousands of lines, you're generating hundreds or thousands of transient subprocesses.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yeah, but I prefer to give the most similar solution to the OP code.

Comment: Understood when there's no penalty, but if the OP is doing something contrary to good practices, I'd argue that it's part of our responsibility to help them improve.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I wonder if that's right. Sometimes it's better to learn one thing at a time. Long answers that change many things can be confusing. Anyway I should have mention it in the post, so thanks for the comment.

Comment: btw, consider `echo "$line"` rather than `echo $line` -- that way you're preserving whitespace types, avoiding glob expansions (ie. if the input string has a `*` in a field, an unquoted `$line` will replace that with a list of files in the current directory), etc.